# In Oracle DB 11.2g, is it possible for the audit trail to explicitly mention account locking events?

Tags: oracle, audit

As it is, the audit trail will show login failures, and an attempt to log into a locked account (ORA-01017 and ORA-28000). What I would like to know is if it's possible for it to make a mention when the locking itself happens, not just in response to a user's actions.

So ideally it will say something to the effect of:

```
user login attempt failed
user login attempt failed
user login attempt failed
user account has been locked for multiple login failures
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is possible. The `AUDIT_ACTIONS` table contains all possible actions in the audit trail. There is a `LOCK` action, but that refers to `LOCK TABLE`.

The `LOCK_DATE` column in `DBA_USERS` contains this information though.